# How to adjust custom css properties dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I am creating a js for an HTML file. I want to manipulate the css of the div.

One of the ways is to use this: -

```
div.style.left = "30px";
```

However, in my code user tells how the HTML is to be manipulated. I want to make it dynamic.
I have set a variable with the property I want to change like this: -

```
let myProperty = "top", value = "30px";
```

Now, I want to use this as my CSS modifier in js like this: -

```
myDiv.style.myProperty = value;
```

I have tried `setAttributes()` which is not working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use square brackets to access an object property using a variable.

For example:

```
let myProperty = "top", value = "30px";
myDiv.style[myProperty] = value;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your style.css create two different styles with different class names.

In your HTML use the default styling.

In your JS:

```js
const someHTMLTag = document.getElementById("demo")

if(condition) {

   someHTMLTag.className = firstStyle

} else {

   someHTMLTag.className = secondStyle

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to get more information, but here's my attempt at providing you with an answer to what you have written in your original question.

You could provide the div with a `class` or `id` in the HTML (`<div id="idName">...</div>`) and have the js file access it via the `DOM`.

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("idName");
myDiv.setAttribute("class", "className");
```

Or

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("idName");
myDiv.style.value = "30px";
```